# Backgroundworker продолжает ли работу, когда приложение свернуто и находится в спящем состоянии?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, backgroundworker

Не смог найти нигде информации, будет ли выполняться код, в частности перекачка и обработка данных по Bluetooth, который выполняется в отдельном потоке с помощью Backgroundworker, когда приложение сворачивается (deactivated) и переходит в спящий (dormant) режим?

Comment: Конечно!
Это же отдельный поток.
Внешний вид окна не влияет на работу потока.

Comment: Внимательнее читайте тэги :). У Windows Phone своя специфика.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет. При переходе в неактивный режим приложение на Windows Phone приостанавливает свою работу. Для того, чтобы иметь возможность выполнять какую-то работу в фоновом режиме, нужно использовать background agents:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202866(v=vs.105).aspx